# Configurations in initializer for custom class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I set configuration settings for a custom gem I'm writing?

From other gems I have seen that the configuration file would look something like this:

```
# config/intializers/magento_client.rb
MagentoClient.configure do |config|
  config.consumer_key = "1234"
  config.consumer_secret = "5678"
  ...
end
```

I would like to work with these configurations in the `prepare_access_token` method:

```
class MagentoClient
  require "oauth"
  require "omniauth"
  require "multi_json"
  require "ostruct"

  def initialize
    @access_token = prepare_access_token
  end

  def find_by(opts) 
    attributes = MultiJson.decode(@access_token.get("/api/rest/products?filter[1][attribute]=isbn&filter[1][eq]=#{opts[:isbn]}&filter[2][attribute]=purchase_type&filter[2][eq]=#{purchase_type_id}").body)
  end

private

  def prepare_access_token
    consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(@@consumer_key, @@consumer_secret, {:site => @@url})
    token_hash = {oauth_token: @@access_key, oauth_token_secret: @@access_secret}
    access_token = OAuth::AccessToken.from_hash(consumer, token_hash)
  end
end
```

I would then like to use the class like this:

```
magento_client = MagentoClient.new
magento_client.find_by(isbn: 1234, purchase_type: "Buy New")
```

And can I name the initializer file with the same name as the class (magento_client)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up going with this solution:

```
# in Gem: lib/magento_rest_api
require "magento_rest_api/version"

module MagentoRestApi
  class << self
    attr_accessor :consumer_key, :consumer_secret, :site, :access_key, :access_secret, :url_params
  end

  def self.configure(&block)
    yield self
  end  

  class Client
    require "oauth"

    def find_by(opts)
      @access_token ||= prepare_access_token       
      [...]   
    end
  private
    def prepare_access_token
      consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(MagentoRestApi.consumer_key, MagentoRestApi.consumer_secret, :site => MagentoRestApi.site)
      token_hash = {oauth_token: MagentoRestApi.access_key, oauth_token_secret: MagentoRestApi.access_secret}
      access_token = OAuth::AccessToken.from_hash(consumer, token_hash)
    end
    [...]
  end
end

# in Rails: config/initializers/magento_rest_api.rb
MagentoRestApi.configure do |config|
  config.consumer_key = "123a"
  [...]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be to have a basic configuration object that lives as a class instance variable within your configurable class:

```
class MyClassConfiguration < Struct.new(:consumer_key, :consumer_secret)
end

class MyClass
  class << self
    def config
      @config ||= MyClassConfiguration.new
    end

    def configure(&block)
      yield config
    end
  end
end

MyClass.configure do |c|
  c.consumer_key = '1234'
  # etc ...
end
```

You could also set up accessors for instances of `MyClass` to easily read the configuration object, and perhaps use `Forwardable` to let you access the configuration variables directly:

```
require 'forwardable'

class MyClass
  extend Forwardable

  def_delegators :config, :consumer_key, :consumer_secret

  def config
    self.class.config
  end
end

MyClass.new.consumer_key #=> '1234'
MyClass.new.consumer_secret #=> '5678'
```

Answer (score 1):

I would look at the ruby documentation on developing engines

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html

Engines provide a simple architecture for assigning configuration parameters. You can define configurable elements as part of the engine definition.

You could also look at existing gems like Carrierwave that have extensive configuration settings.

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave